"If…, he can /will be able to kill the dictator" What is the difference in meaning?
What’s the difference?
“He’s the bravest person I’ve ever seen.

If you give him a knife, he can kill the dictator.

If you give him a knife, he’ll be able to kill the dictator”


What’s the difference in meaning between these two sentences?
PS: I am asking about “can” vs “will be able to” not “can” vs “able to” so please don’t tell me they are the same.

Are you intending to highlight the difference in tense—present vice future? If so, I suggest you edit your question to make that clear. Otherwise, the only answers you’re likely to receive are the ones you have asked not to receive.

@Mari-LouA - not wishing to be a diagnostician, but neurodiversity can include long meaningless obsessions with words.

@MichaelHarvey that's a fair evaluation, in the past I had considered that possibility myself, but today something snapped in me. I'll delete my insensitive comment.

@Mari-LouA - that's your choice, but I'd leave it if it were mine. Back in the day, on the Usenet group alt.usage.english, there was a guy who asked hundreds of questions about the word 'rare', to the eventual annoyance of just about everyone. Eventually his mother came on and explained that he was in an assisted living facility in New York.

The linked question doesn't really answer this particular user's question. But I think my answer to What’s the difference between “can” and “will be able to” in this context? Please don’t tell me they are the same should have been enough. If that doesn't satisfy this OP, probably nothing will, so who cares what it's closed against?

@FumbleFingers your answer is to a previous question by the same user. That question with your answer has been chosen to close two other posts by the same author. Let's see if James K's answer helps the OP. I'm betting my money that the post is not unfamiliar but… there are only so many ways to ask whether two sentences are different (all the while insisting that native speakers do not respond there is barely or no difference).

@Mari-LouA: Well, in some contexts there is (or at least could be) a difference. The problem is this OP pays little or no attention to context, as can be seen from the comments under Michael's answer below.

There is no difference; they are equivalent in meaning.
We can use a present tense verb ('can') to discuss a future or hypothetical possibility, whether that is one of ability, permission, or entitlement.
If you buy a ticket, you can [or will be able to] ride the train tonight.
If you wear a hat, you can [or will be able to] keep your head dry in the rain.

Note that: “if you practice, you can sing” is wrong. Please explain why.

@ChienTeLu - it isn't wrong.

It is according to most native speakers.

@ChienTeLu isolated phrases without context can suggest that something is not idiomatic BUT in the right context, that short sentence can sound very natural:   If you practice for long enough and do your vocal exercises, you can sing in the local choir.

@ChienTeLu: You shouldn't say things like that to competent native Anglophones, since you're clearly way out of your depth here. In your specific example in the question, it's almost impossible to contrive any difference in meaning between can and will be able to. But in the case of If you practice, you can / will be able to sing, it's far more likely that the can version implies speaker will allow addressee to sing (in some show he's staging, perhaps), where the will be able to version refers to an ability the addressee could acquire by practicing.

@ChienTeLu - when did you ask 'most native speakers'?

@FumbleFingers - if you do breathing exercises, you can (probably) hold your breath for longer. I'm doing that at the moment, and it seems to work, Also my peak flow measurements are up by 20%.

“If you practice, you can sing” might be misleading (some people will never be able to sing properly no matter how much they practice), but it is not 'wrong' grammatically.

I find it hard to see even a nuance of difference between can and will be able to in the context of doing those breathing exercises. But I'm a bear of very little brain, so I stand to be corrected on that one!

“You will be able to hold your breath longer” is correct……

@ChienTeLu - my version is correct too.

Much more comment malarkey, and I'll delete my answer and all of the comments will be one with Nineveh and Tyre.

Michael: Hopefully this comment isn't "more malarkey", but are you suggesting that the implications of If you practice, you can / will be able to sing could be affected by whether the speaker suspects he might be talking to one of those people who will never be able to sing properly? There truly can be a difference if speaker is directing a musical performance and speaking to someone who wants to be included, but I can't think of any other contexts where it might be "ambiguous" if we don't have a full context.
